# How to make special characters?

Tags: c++, special-characters

I want the console to display the character '♞'.

I use:

> wchar_t tab2[8][8];
>
> tab2[x1][x2]=L'♞';

For example, but for this character, the console displays "9822".

My code (I post just the main code, the rest is irrelevant for this problem).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cwchar>
#include "fonctions.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool tab1[8][8];
    wchar_t tab2[8][8];
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            tab1[i][j]=false;
            tab2[i][j]=L' ';
        //  fgets(tab2[i][j], 1, stdin);

        }
    }

    int b=0, c=0;
    cout<<"Veuillez entrer les coordonnées de la case de départ souhaitée!"<<endl;
    do
    {
        cout<<"Abscisse: ";
        cin>>b;
    }while((b<1)||(b>8));
    do
    {
        cout<<"Ordonnée: ";
        cin>>c;
    }while((c<1)||(c>8));

    tab1[b-1][c-1]=true;
    tab2[b-1][c-1]=9822;

  int q1=b-1;
    int q2=c-1;
    vector<Point> v=Combinations(q1,q2,tab1);
    int continuation=0;

    while(!v.empty()&&(continuation==0))
    {

        Point p1=TheRightPoint(v,tab1);

        int x1=p1.GetX();
        int x2=p1.GetY();

        cout<<"+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+"<<endl;
        cout<<"+"<<tab2[0][0]<<"+"<<tab2[1][0]<<"+"<<tab2[2][0]<<"+"<<tab2[3][0]<<"+"<<tab2[4][0]<<"+"<<tab2[5][0]<<"+"<<tab2[6][0]<<"+"<<tab2[7][0]<<"+"<<endl;
        cout<<"+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+"<<endl;
        cout<<"+"<<tab2[0][1]<<"+"<<tab2[1][1]<<"+"<<tab2[2][1]<<"+"<<tab2[3][1]<<"+"<<tab2[4][1]<<"+"<<tab2[5][1]<<"+"<<tab2[6][1]<<"+"<<tab2[7][1]<<"+"<<endl;
        cout<<"+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+"<<endl;
        cout<<"+"<<tab2[0][2]<<"+"<<tab2[1][2]<<"+"<<tab2[2][2]<<"+"<<tab2[3][2]<<"+"<<tab2[4][2]<<"+"<<tab2[5][2]<<"+"<<tab2[6][2]<<"+"<<tab2[7][2]<<"+"<<endl;
        cout<<"+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+"<<endl;
        cout<<"+"<<tab2[0][3]<<"+"<<tab2[1][3]<<"+"<<tab2[2][3]<<"+"<<tab2[3][3]<<"+"<<tab2[4][3]<<"+"<<tab2[5][3]<<"+"<<tab2[6][3]<<"+"<<tab2[7][3]<<"+"<<endl;
        cout<<"+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+"<<endl;
        cout<<"+"<<tab2[0][4]<<"+"<<tab2[1][4]<<"+"<<tab2[2][4]<<"+"<<tab2[3][4]<<"+"<<tab2[4][4]<<"+"<<tab2[5][4]<<"+"<<tab2[6][4]<<"+"<<tab2[7][4]<<"+"<<endl;
        cout<<"+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+"<<endl;
        cout<<"+"<<tab2[0][5]<<"+"<<tab2[1][5]<<"+"<<tab2[2][5]<<"+"<<tab2[3][5]<<"+"<<tab2[4][5]<<"+"<<tab2[5][5]<<"+"<<tab2[6][5]<<"+"<<tab2[7][5]<<"+"<<endl;
        cout<<"+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+"<<endl;
        cout<<"+"<<tab2[0][6]<<"+"<<tab2[1][6]<<"+"<<tab2[2][6]<<"+"<<tab2[3][6]<<"+"<<tab2[4][6]<<"+"<<tab2[5][6]<<"+"<<tab2[6][6]<<"+"<<tab2[7][6]<<"+"<<endl;
        cout<<"+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+"<<endl;
        cout<<"+"<<tab2[0][7]<<"+"<<tab2[1][7]<<"+"<<tab2[2][7]<<"+"<<tab2[3][7]<<"+"<<tab2[4][7]<<"+"<<tab2[5][7]<<"+"<<tab2[6][7]<<"+"<<tab2[7][7]<<"+"<<endl;
        cout<<"+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+"<<endl;

        tab1[x1][x2]=true;
        tab2[x1][x2]=L'♞';
        //fgets(tab2[x1][x2], 1, stdin);


        cout<<"Taper un autre chiffre que 0 pour arrêter!"<<endl;
        cin>>continuation;
        v=Combinations(x1,x2,tab1);

    }

    return 0;


}
```

What the console displays:

```
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
+32+32+32+32+32+32+32+32+
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
+32+32+9822+32+32+32+32+32+
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
+32+32+32+32+32+32+32+32+
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
+32+32+32+9822+32+32+32+32+
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
+32+32+32+32+32+32+32+32+
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
+32+32+32+32+32+32+32+32+
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
+32+32+32+32+32+32+32+32+
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
+32+32+32+32+32+32+32+32+
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Comment: I'll throw out that it probably depends a lot on your console, what encoding you use, and possibly your operating system.  For example, I wrote a program and encrypted and decrypted text using random UTF-8 chars.  The higher level chars would show up as /234 /362 /423 and stuff like that in Mac OS Terminal, but would render as characters from other languages on Windows Command Line.

Comment: I work on a Linux(Ubuntu) O.S

Comment: What's the full piece of code you're running?  How are you formatting the output?

Comment: the question is missing code between the assignment and "the console displays". There are many ways to make the console display something, some of them work with wchar_t, some don't. What did you try and why?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::wcout`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/wcout/) instead of `std::cout` for `wchar_t` strings.

Comment: That's better, but there is the character '^' instead of '♞'.  Why ?

Comment: @TotorAndMimine ♞ is `0x265E` and ^ is `0x005E`, so it appears your console may be truncating unicode characters.

Comment: Also try `L'\u265E'` instead of `L'♞';`